# Denying commits that are not merge commits

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge, git-workflow

Here's a workflow that I use:

1. Make changes in branch `A`.
2. Checkout branch `B`.
3. Merge changes from branch `A` to branch `B`.
4. Sync (push and pull) branch `B` to a remote branch.
5. Checkout branch `A`.
6. Go back to *step 1*.

The problem is that sometimes I forget step 5 and instead of branch `A`, I make changes to branch `B`.

Is it possible to configure branch `B` so that it would deny "regular" commits and allow only merge commits?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing this work manually I would recommend using a workflow like [git-flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/).

Or you can write a simple script which does this work for you.

If you prefer doing things manually, you can use a [git-hook](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) which does the merging of your `B` branch and the pull action automatically.